# summary() function causing a fatal error in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, fatal-error

I am trying to run a simple `summary()` of a logisitic `glm` and repeatedly get a fatal error in RStudio. I was able to run this same code flawlessly yesterday and beginning yesterday evening I kept getting the fatal error bomb.

The `glm` was constructed on roughly 2.6 million rows with 100+ variables. Once the `glm` is constructed, the R environment is consuming 21.8GB of my 64GB of RAM.

I have tried updating all of my packages that are loaded in the environment when the error occurs but I'm not sure that is even necessary since the error occurs on such a basic R function. Below is the session info.

```
# R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
# [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
# [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

# attached base packages:
# 1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] tools_3.2.1
```

UPDATE: I was away from my workstation for roughly 1 hour and 15 minutes and the `summary()` function now works without crashing RStudio. Now the question becomes: why does this sort of thing happen in the first place?

Comment: Do you get the error if you run the code just using RGui?

Comment: Granted this is coming after my update above but, no, I did not get an error when running in the RGui.

Comment: @Dason - I currently have the same problem as the original poster, but it only occurs in RStudio, not RGui or an Emacs ESS R process. My glm is much smaller, however.

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: rsession.exe
  Application Version: 0.99.467.0
  Application Timestamp: 00000000
  Fault Module Name: ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.17936
  Fault Module Timestamp: 55a68e0c
  Exception Code: c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0000000000054ac1
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: abcc
  Additional Information 2: abcc8f7853b48d9807d6d51eb1fa5df9
  Additional Information 3: abcc
  Additional Information 4: abcc8f7853b48d9807d6d51eb1fa5df9

Comment: @Dason actually I take that back, I get the error in RGui as well, but not when running R in emacs ESS